# AngularJS bootstrap progressbar updates incorrectly when adding dependency to ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs

I have an [AngularJS bootstrap progressbar](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar) on my page, but when I add `ngAnimate` as a dependency to my module the progress bar updates incorrectly. **See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6VPDSf1HBzv1OAxVx9gY?p=preview).**

It's like a bar is added for each update-animation, and when the animation is done the bar is removed again.

If I remove `ngAnimate` as dependency, it works as expected, but I need `ngAnimate` for other animations...

Is this a bug in the `progress` directive or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sound's like a bug to me.

Comment: It was a bug, which was solved in the newest release (angular-1.2.0-rc3). [Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OphjnWmcBygyobiqfP42?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the additional link to the animation resource. The animation is built-in.

http://plnkr.co/edit/LgoVMznuN9zp3RlFFdlp?p=preview

Comment: I need `angular-animate.js` for other animations, e.g animating `enter` and `leave` in `ngRepeat`. The AngularJS core doesn't provide direct support for animations anymore in version 1.2, see e.g. [this article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#what-has-changed-from-1-1-5-to-1-2)